# CentOS7 kernel upgrade corrupt grub

Tags: linux, kernel, grub2

We have HP DL360 G8 server and installed CentOS7 64bit on it and everything was working fine but as soon as we did `yum update` on full system and reboot it got stuck at grub `grub>` so i did following to recover

```
grub>set root=(hd0,msdos1)
grub>linux16 /vmlinux-<old kernel> root=/dev/sdx rw
grub>initrd16 /initramfs-XXXXX
grub>boot
```

Which boot system successfully and i did `grub2-install /dev/sda` and reboot again but still its getting stuck in `grub>` i have tried `UEFI` gru2 install method also but still no luck, even i un-install latest kernel but no luck :(

what could be wrong?

Comment: Any suggestion, I have upgraded BIOS firmware also but i didn't find `System ROM Bootlock` firmware i don't know what is that, do you think this is hardware issue?

Answer (score 1):

Found problem:

It was stupid RAID issue we had (fakeRAID) setup which was broken somehow so it was presenting two disk in linux fdisk and found grub was written on both disk.

Solution was when you use fakeRAID then you need special driver kernel module also you need to disable `AHCI` module when you install linux, so i have add `blacklist=ahci` in PXE kickstart file and it fixed all issue.